# How to continue collect motion sensor data on apple watch?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, gyroscope, core-motion

I'm developing an app on apple watch which needs continuous access to gyroscope and accelerometer data. But once the watch rotates, the screen turns off and apparently it stops accessing motion data while the screen is off. I tried to keep the screen on but apple watch doesn't have that feature, any thoughts around this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to start an [HKWorkoutSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutsession).

> The app can continue to access data from Apple Watch’s sensors in the background, letting you keep the app up to date at all times. For example, a running app can continue to track the user’s heart rate, ensuring that the most recent heart rate data is displayed whenever the user raises their wrist.